# Disable JavaScript from running in JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx

I would like to know if JavaScript can be disabled in `WebView` of JavaFX. I have searched the web but cant get any information about this.

The link in [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) website says that JavaScript can be enabled and disabled but can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set Javascript disabled on the [`WebEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)) itself that the WebView controls.

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```